# MakeTextWritingDirectionRightToLeft(null) in xamarin iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to achieve `RightToLeft` direction in my project. Other things working fine but label isn't moving to right in iOS for that purpose I have created a `LabelRenderer` in which I'm passing this method `MakeTextWritingDirectionRightToLeft(null)` but I'm getting exception

```
Objective-C exception thrown. Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: -[UILabel makeTextWritingDirectionRightToLeft:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd2fb68b680
```

Can anyone tell me what to pass in the parameter of this function instead of null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use following code to achieve RightToLeft direction in my project.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Label), typeof(CustomLabel))]
public class CustomLabel: LabelRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            Control.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Right;
            
        }
    }
```